# LINQ querying results for a decimal sum between two dates

Tags: c#, linq, decimal

Attempting to query results between two dates, get a column value, and sum that into a decimal.  Unfortunately, every time I pass in different dates - I get all of the results.  Something is wrong with getting the results between two dates.  Any help is appreciated.

Here's what I have now:

```
 private static decimal QuerySales(DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime, IQueryable<ProductsSummary> summaries)
    {
        var relevantSummaries = (from summary in summaries
                     where ((summary.Date >= startDateTime.Date) && (summary.Date <= endDateTime.Date))
                     select summary);

        var netSales = (from records in relevantSummaries
                      select summaries.Sum(x => x.NetSales)).ToList();

        decimal sales = netSales.Any() ? netSales[0] : 0;
        return sales;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you doing `from records in relevantSummaries` and then `select summaries`...? You are summing the whole table (`summaries`) every time instead of using `records`. And should `records` be singular? Did you mean to just `relevantSummaries.Sum(s => s.NetSales)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler, using the [Method Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq) for LINQ:

```
  return summaries
   .Where(s => s.Date >= startDateTime.Date && s.Date <= endDateTime.Date)
   .Sum(s => s.NetSales)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
 private static decimal QuerySales(DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime, IQueryable<ProductsSummary> summaries)
    {
        decimal sales = 0;
        var relevantSummaries = (from summary in summaries
                     where ((summary.Date >= startDateTime.Date) 
                            && (summary.Date <= endDateTime.Date))
                     select summary.NetSales);

        if (relevantSummaries != null)
        {
           sales = relevantSummaries.Sum();
        }

        return sales;
    }
```